# opencv2.framework/opencv2(shapedescr.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE)

Tags: objective-c, opencv, xcode8

Ld /Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MMCamScanner-ayaaebcalydwgeeenncrtqxmthsh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MMCamScanner.app/MMCamScanner normal arm64
    cd /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/SwiftDemo/MMCamScanner
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3
    export PATH="/Users/XXXXXXX/Downloads/Xcode

2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/XXXXXXX/Downloads/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Users/XXXXXXX/Downloads/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Users/sravanthigumma/Downloads/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk -L/Users/XXXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MMCamScanner-ayaaebcalydwgeeenncrtqxmthsh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/XXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MMCamScanner-ayaaebcalydwgeeenncrtqxmthsh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/XXXX/Desktop/SwiftDemo/MMCamScanner -filelist /Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MMCamScanner-ayaaebcalydwgeeenncrtqxmthsh/Build/Intermediates/MMCamScanner.build/Debug-iphoneos/MMCamScanner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MMCamScanner.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=10.3 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MMCamScanner-ayaaebcalydwgeeenncrtqxmthsh/Build/Intermediates/MMCamScanner.build/Debug-iphoneos/MMCamScanner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MMCamScanner_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libc++ -framework opencv2 -framework TesseractOCR -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreImage -lstdc++ -framework CoreTelephony -framework MobileCoreServices -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MMCamScanner-ayaaebcalydwgeeenncrtqxmthsh/Build/Intermediates/MMCamScanner.build/Debug-iphoneos/MMCamScanner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MMCamScanner_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/XXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MMCamScanner-ayaaebcalydwgeeenncrtqxmthsh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MMCamScanner.app/MMCamScanner

Comment: You should format your question to follow rules.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Settings > Choose Enable Bitcode and Set it value to YES.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same. Is this a requirement in XCode 14? In 13.2 everything was working correctly.